# How do I gain root access to my own folders when using file manager?

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, xfce, directory

Basically I want to be able to right click on one of my folders and use something like 'Thunar Root', type in my admin password and continue to use it. Now I've quite a big trouble getting some files to my admin privileged folders. Also, isn't the default XFCE file manager called Thunar? Why is it called plainly 'File Manager'?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using "Custom Actions".

- **GUI method:**

Open Thunar and go to the following option:

[image]

There, select Add, and write something like this:

[image]

After this change, restart Thunar, and now, once you right-click, you will see something like this:

[image]

That will prompt a window asking you to introduce the password, and you are done.

More information can be found [here](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions).

- **Non-GUI Method:**

Go to `~/.config/Thunar/` and open the file called `uca.xml` **with a text editor** (double-clicking will open a browser). Then, create a new entry like this (here, with the same properties as in the GUI method):

```
<action>
    <icon>changes-prevent</icon>
    <name>Open Folder as root</name>
    <unique-id>1426762241486505-1</unique-id>
    <command>gksudo thunar %f</command>
    <description>Open a folder as super user</description>
    <patterns>*</patterns>
    <directories/>
</action>
```

Save, restart thunar, and enjoy!

---

Finally, regarding your naming question, the program is called Thunar (as opposed to Nautilus in Gnome), but it is a File Manager (category of program), so I imagine that is why it gets the generic name. In fact, from a terminal, you can start it with `thunar` but not with `file-manager` or so.

---

Note: Another useful option is to **open a file as Root** (generally a script or text file). The code would be something like this:

```
<action>
    <icon>locked</icon>
    <name>Open File as root</name>
    <unique-id>1426762251695002-2</unique-id>
    <command>gksudo mousepad %f</command>
    <description>Open a file as super user</description>
    <patterns>*</patterns>
    <text-files/>
</action>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can type

```
$gksu thunar %f
```

to access thunar as root

Answer (score 1):

In the current version (4.16.8) there is already a "Thunar Root" action predefined and its command is `pkexec thunar %f`. `$gksu thunar %f` doesn't work.